# Broadcast receiver for checking internet connection in Flutter

Tags: service, flutter, broadcastreceiver, connectivity

I want to send an email. But if there is no internet connection I want to listen if  the connection is resumed, and try to send the email again. Even when the app has been closed.

Is there an equivalent for BroadcastReceiver and Service in Flutter?
It should work on Android and iOS.

Comment: There is the https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/connectivity plugin to check if the network is connected. You can repeatedly try to reach a server in the internet to check if the network is connected to the internet. You can use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_alarm_manager to make this work in the background. I don't think there is something simple(r) available yet.

Comment: There is an article on Medium about android_alarm_manager and the alternative for iOS. iOS does not provide the same features as Android for background execution.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are new versions of plugins mentioned in the comment by [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%c3%bcnter-z%c3%b6chbauer).

- [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus)
- [android_alarm_manager_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus)

And for the alternative of android_alarm_manager_plus for iOS, [this blog post](https://medium.com/vrt-digital-studio/flutter-workmanager-81e0cfbd6f6e) featured [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) plugin. Which uses the newer [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) API

The fluttercommunity as mentioned [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48151#issuecomment-570742406), is currently working on this feature that will closely match the existing Android workmanager implementation.

See also "[Checking Network Connectivity In Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/checking-network-connectivity-in-flutter-7985659d6e06)" for some good sample of implementing connectivity plugin.